# Clipboard file sync without full remote

Tags: clipboard, file

I would like to have something like the clipboard file sync in AnyDesk and Teamviewer but without all the rest of the features like remote desktop, etc.

Something that i can keep running in the background and when i copy a file on one PC i can just paste it on the other PC (should support multi-select)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for sync to multiply hosts file(s) and directories is to use [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/). You install the client and when you work on local copy and save it it sync over the other hosts which have installed the client (and authenticate with the same account)

P.S. No affiliate with the developer of this software.

Comment: I was not talking about simple sync, i was explicitly mentioning drag & drop.

Comment: @Bluscream, with OneDrive you can perfectly use drag-and-drop from the OS you use